# Is it possible to add a new algorithm to cryptopp benchmarks?

Tags: c++, cryptography, aes, benchmarking, crypto++

I want to bench an algorithm (aes version) which is not in cryptopp benchmarks. If it is possible, how can I do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By getting the benchmark code and putting it in? It's open source, right?

Comment: Yes, you can download it from cryptopp.com and It's open source.

Comment: You've answered your own question, didn't you? If you can download the code, because it is open source, why can't you add some code?

Comment: Also see [Benchmarks](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Benchmarks) on the Crypto++ wiki and [Calculate time encryption of AES/CCM in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47956337/608639) on Stack Overflow.